# Generate keys with k3d3 / ed25519-java

Tags: keys, ed25519

I'm trying to use a [java implementation of ed25519](https://github.com/k3d3/ed25519-java/blob/master/ed25519.java).

In the code, I can't find any functions that generate keys.

My experience with cryptography is limited to about three weeks of asking questions on stack.

Does the code generate keys?  If so, which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed25519 is a specific implementation of EdDSA using the Twisted Edwards curve:

```
x^2 + y^2 = 1 + (121665/121666) * (x^2)(y^2)
```

It's known as high speed high security signature algorithm. For using the code you pointed out, you need to feed sk, pk, m, sm.

So first you need to call `publickey` function with `sk`, then call `signature` function with `m`, `sk` and `pk`. `PK` is byte array returned from `publickey` function.

An example entry:

```
9d61b19deffd5a60ba844af492ec2cc44449c5697b326919703bac031cae7f60d75a980182b10ab7d54bfed3c964073a0ee172f3daa62325af021a68f707511a:d75a980182b10ab7d54bfed3c964073a0ee172f3daa62325af021a68f707511a::e5564300c360ac729086e2cc806e828a84877f1eb8e5d974d873e065224901555fb8821590a33bacc61e39701cf9b46bd25bf5f0595bbe24655141438e7a100b:
```

It's sk:pk:m:sm

You can find more info at:
http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/index.html

Comment: Thank you so very much M. C.!  I think I understand, but how is `sk` generated?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: SK is signing key, there is a Python code here https://github.com/warner/python-ed25519/blob/master/src/ed25519/keys.py  which does have a function called create_keypair, that's how you create key pairs

Comment: @Gracchus: Private signing keys can be generated from just the 32-byte seed, but require additional work before you can make signatures

Comment: More info: http://blog.mozilla.org/warner/2011/11/29/ed25519-keys/